# Как выполнить -x * x один раз за циклом, вместо того чтобы выполнять его много раз в цикле? При этом результат должен вывода не должен изменится

Tags: c++, c

Как в приведеном ниже коде выполнить `-x * x` один раз за циклом, вместо того, чтобы выполнять его много раз в цикле? При этом результат должен вывода должен остаться прежним

```
int main() 
    {
       double j,  i = 5, x = 0.1;
       j = x;
       while (i--)
       {
           j *= -x * x;
           printf("%lf\n", j);
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Ну стыдно даже отвечать...

```
int main() 
{
   double j,  i = 5, x = 0.1;
   j = x;
   x *= x;
   while (i--)
   {
       j *= -x;
       printf("%lf\n", j);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: да блин я с этим мучался на протяжении 10 минут, я устал((

Comment: Он мучился — только подумать! — целых 10 минут! А как люди работали, когда ruSO и Интернета не было? 10 минут подумал, не получилось — все, письмо в журнал? Интересно, если девушку за 10 минут не охмурите — тоже друзей попросите с ней ....? Господи, что за люди пошли... :( Судя по всему, код тоже у кого-то выпрошен...

Comment: Удивляет не наличие таких людей, лентяи всегда были, есть и будут. Удивляет, что человек даже не осознает, *что* делает...

Comment: ладно ладно. если признаться я страдал на протяжении 2 месяцев, просто стыдно признавать